# what is this card game about making an anime or anime character

Tags: identify-this-game

this card game is sort of like super fight but you use cards that have a single word or phrase on each of them. you combine them in the order that you want to go with a topic the "voter" (basically if it was Cards against humanity they would be the black card) draws. then you go around and argue about why your card combination should win.

Comment: Bah.. i know the game.. i found the PDF... just on a harddrive i don't have access to. I'll see what i can find. I think it was a KS game (not that that helps much)

Answer (score 2):

Channel A

[image: Channel A Box Art]

[Home](https://yarukizerogames.com/my-games/channel-a/) | [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/134637/channel) | [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFQnwHfopgg) (NSFW - Skantily clad women)

Phew that took a while to track down. I knew it had "A" in the name somewhere but

> If you could make an anime series, what would it be about?
>
> In this randomly creative party game you’re part of Channel A’s struggle to come up with an anime series that will be the next big hit. You know what general premise the network wants, and it’s up to you to stitch together a title from random words and pitch a series to win over the fans.

Comment: See also: Slash: Romance without boundaries (http://www.gamesbyplaydate.com/slash)

Comment: Thank you. and i know it was hard to track down i just didn't remember AT ALL what it was called. i was looking for a solid hour and a half.

Comment: so many anime games.. so much comes up that isn't what you look like especially when you consider there is an Anime deck for both Superfight and Cards against Humanity.